# Why we need to create a Workbook before reading the Excel file using Apache POI?

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

Please find  a Code snippet below

```
public class DataDriven_GetDataExcel {

public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException, EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException {   

//1 Getting Control over File
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\bewosaurabh\\Documents\\GetDataFile.xlsx");

//2 Creating a Workbook
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

//3 Getting Control over Sheet
Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
            .
            ......
```

What I don't understand is why we need to create a Workbook before reading the Excel file?
An Excel file is also called as Workbook (as we can see in below picture).
[image]

When we Create an excel file that means we are creating a Workbook. From there, we access the Sheets followed by rows and columns.

I don't understand why we write write `WorkbookFactory.create(fis);` when we already have a 'Workbook'
We should have some methods to get the Workbook we have created like we have for Rows(getRow), Sheets (getSheet), Cells (getCell).

Can you help me understand POI?

Comment: `WorkbookFactory.create` does not create a workbook (an Excel file). It instantiates a class that represents a workbook.

Comment: Ohh..okay, Thanks a ton for clarifying that @GSerg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What `Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);` does is:

Instantiating a `Java` object, which implements [Workbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html), from the content of the file read using the file input stream. After that the `Workbook` object is then located in memory. And only after having access to this `Workbook` object we can use its methods.

If we would use `Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file);`, that is using a `File` instead of an `InputStream`, then the `WorkbookFactory` would create the `Workbook` object directly from the file. The advantage of this is that not the whole file content must be read into the memory. So we have a lower memory footprint. The disadvantage is that the file which is opened for reading cannot be used for writing the same time. So we cannot write changings we have made using the methods of `Workbook` into the same file we have read the `Workbook` from.

If memory footprint is a bigger issue, then for XSSF (`*.xlsx`), we can get at the underlying XML data and process it using [XSSF and SAX (Event API)](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#XSSF+and+SAX+%28Event+API%29). Using this we need not to instantiate a `Workbook` object. Instead we are reading and parsing the `XML` directly from the `OPCPackage` which is a `ZipPackage` in case of XSSF (`*.xlsx`) since a `*.xlsx` is simply a `ZIP` archive containing a directory structure containing `XML` files and other files.

Since a `*.xlsx` is simply a `ZIP` archive we also could opening it as [FileSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) gotten from [FileSystems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html) and then process its content totally independent from third party libraries. But this will be the most challenging approach.

Comment: Thank you, for prompt reply and detailed explanation @Axel Richter. I got it.