# Why can't I prevent Apache POI from altering the source file?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am opening an Excel file (the source) in Java using an Apache POI Workbook, altering data in a certain set of cells, saving the Workbook to a separate file, then closing the Workbook (because the documentation states to close the Workbook, even if it is read-only).

POI alters the data in the source Excel file every time.  I have tried a few different methods to prevent this according to recommendations from the POI documentation, but these methods fail.

Here are two attempts that should work in theory, but do not.

**Attempt 1 - set the source file to read only**

```
File file = new File("{path-to-existing-source-file}");

file.setReadOnly();

Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file); // throws a FileNotFoundException
```

A `FileNotFoundException` for "Access is denied" is thrown at `WorkbookFactory.create(file)`:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: {path-to-source-file-that-exists} (Access is denied)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.nio.FileBackedDataSource.newSrcFile(FileBackedDataSource.java:158)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.nio.FileBackedDataSource.<init>(FileBackedDataSource.java:60)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:224)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:172)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:298)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:271)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:252)
at com.stackoverflow.MyClass(MyClass.java:71)
```

The source file exists, and it is validly read-only.

**Attempt 2 - use the POI API constructor which allows read-only to be explicitly set**

```
File file = new File("{path-to-existing-source-file}");
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file, null, true);  // true is read-only

// dataBean is just a container bean with the appropriate reference values
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(dataBean.getSheetName());
Row row = sheet.getRow(dataBean.getRowNumber());
Cell cell = row.getCell(dataBean.getColumnNumber());
cell.setCellValue(dataBean.getValue());

// target is another File reference
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("path-to-target-file"));
workbook.write(outStream);   // throws InvalidOperationException
```

An `InvalidOperationException` is thrown during the write call:

```
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: 
Operation not allowed, document open in read only mode!
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.throwExceptionIfReadOnly(OPCPackage.java:551)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.removePart(OPCPackage.java:955)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.getOutputStream(PackagePart.java:531)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.commit(XSSFWorkbook.java:1770)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.onSave(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:463)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:236)
at com.stackoverflow.MyClass(MyClass.java:90)
```

"Operation not allowed, document open in read only mode!".  Of course it is set to read-only; I don't want the source written to, I just want all the data to go to a new target.

What can I set or change to not alter the source when using POI?

Our current workaround is to create a duplicate source file, but that is not a good solution.

Comment: You need to open a second workbook and write to that one mate, I did something like that a few months ago I will check

Comment: What do you mean by that; create a second workbook using all the data from the original as a source, and then manipulate the second workbook?  Can you provide a code sample?  I'll see if I can find anything online regarding it.

Comment: The usage of `File` for creating `XSSFWorkbook` has that disadvantages. This is known issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929312/apache-poi-appending-data-to-xlsx-file-when-task-ran-twice/55937539#55937539 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146161/apache-poi-fileinputstream-works-file-object-fails-nullpointerexception/46149469#46149469 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708114/why-we-need-to-create-a-workbook-before-reading-the-excel-file-using-apache-poi/45709920#45709920. Do using `FileInputStream` instead of `File` for creating the `XSSFWorkbook`.

Comment: @JoshDM yes, create a second workbout which is the one that is gonna call .write(), the other one is just for reading brother, check out my answer carefully I commented

Comment: @AxelRichter - I was informed that the FileInputStream process was attempted and it altered the original; however when we retried it, wrapped in a BufferedInputStream, it succeeded and will be our code going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to handle XSSF and HSSF; this is how it was accomplished:

```
void handle(File inFile, File outFile) throws IOException {    

    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inFile);
    workbook.setMissingCellPolicy(MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);  // LINE NOT REQUIRED

    if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {

        handleXSSF((XSSFWorkbook) workbook, outFile);

    } else if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {

        handleHSSF((HSSFWorkbook) workbook, outFile);

    } else {

        throw new IOException("Unrecognized Workbook Type " + workbook.getClass().getName());
    }
}

void handleHSSF(HSSFWorkbook hWorkbook, File outFile) throws IOException {

    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);    
        hWorkbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();

    } finally {

        try { 

            hWorkbook.close();

        } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }
}

void handleXSSF(XSSFWorkbook xWorkbook, File outFile) throws IOException {

    SXSSFWorkbook sWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(xWorkbook, 100);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);    
        sWorkbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();

    } finally {

        try { 

            sWorkbook.close();

        } catch (Exception ignore) {}

        try { 

            sWorkbook.dispose();

        } catch (Exception ignore) {}

        try { 

            xWorkbook.close();

        } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and solved it by using a `FileInputStream` instead of a `File`.

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
```

becomes:

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file));
```

Comment: This is the only answser that works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two workbooks, one where you get the datafrom (read) and another one you write to.

Look man, this is how I did a few months ago, please notice that I use .write() on the second workbook (hssfWorkbookNew), not the one im using to read the data from, read it carefully. This code is just for getting first sheet of a XLS excel and copying it to a new file.

```
// this method generates a new excelFile based on the excelFile he receives

public void generarXLS(File excelFile, File excelNewFile) {
        InputStream excelStream = null;
        OutputStream excelNewOutputStream = null;
        try {
            excelStream = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
            excelNewOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(excelNewFile);
            // Representation of highest level of excel sheet.
            HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(excelStream);
            HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbookNew = new HSSFWorkbook();

            // Chose the sheet that we pass as parameter.
            HSSFSheet hssfSheet = hssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);

            // Create new sheet we are gonna use.
            HSSFSheet hssfSheetNew = hssfWorkbookNew.createSheet("Copy-Copia");

            // Create new sheet where we will copy the data

            // Object that allow us to read a row from the sheet and extract the data from the cells
            HSSFRow hssfRow;
            HSSFRow hssfRowNew; // for hssfSheetNew
            // Initialize the object that reads value of cell
            HSSFCell cellNew;
            // Get number of rows of the sheet
            int rows = hssfSheet.getLastRowNum();
            String cellValue;

            // Style of the cell border, color background and pattern (fill pattern) used.
            CellStyle style = hssfWorkbookNew.createCellStyle();
            // Definition of the font of the cell.

            // Iterate trhough all rows to get the cells and copy them to the new sheet
            for (Row row : hssfSheet) {
                hssfRowNew = hssfSheetNew.createRow(row.getRowNum());

                if (row.getRowNum() > 999999) {
                    break;
                }

                for (Cell cell : row) {

                    cellValue = (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) ? cell.getStringCellValue()
                            : (cell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) ? "" + cell.getNumericCellValue()
                                    : (cell.getCellType() == CellType.BOOLEAN) ? "" + cell.getBooleanCellValue()
                                            : (cell.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK) ? ""
                                                    : (cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) ? "FORMULA"
                                                            : (cell.getCellType() == CellType.ERROR) ? "ERROR" : "";

                    cellNew = hssfRowNew.createCell(cell.getColumnIndex(), CellType.STRING);
                    cellNew.setCellValue(cellValue);

                }
            }
            // NOTICE how I write to the new workbook
            hssfWorkbookNew.write(excelNewOutputStream);
            hssfWorkbook.close();
            hssfWorkbookNew.close();
            excelNewOutputStream.close();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Constantes.MSG_EXITO, "Informacion", 1);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "file not found", "Error", 0);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error processing the file", "Error", 0);

        } finally {
            try {
                excelStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error processing the file after closing it): " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Notice that I use one HSSFWorkbook for reading and another one for writing, you have to do like that

Comment: I did something similar, but a lot shorter: ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4096);  workbook.write(os);
workbook.close();  workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()));  However, we'll be using the BufferedInputStream create call suggested in another comment to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could also just use the create signature

`Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("//server/path/file.ext"), null, true);`

to ask POI to open the spreadsheet read only?